# "margin-top" e "margin-bottom" se sobrepondo, por quê?

Tags: css, html, margens

Eu tenho três elementos `div`:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.box {
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 48px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 7px 0;
}
```

Logo concluímos que o espaçamento vertical entre elas deveria ser de 14 pixeis (7px + 7px).

Porém isso acontece somente quando eu defino `display:inline-block;`:

```css
.box {
    ... /* definições apresentadas em cima */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Caso contrário o espaçamento entre cada `div` fica com `7px`, é como se uma margem sobrepusesse à outra.

#### Alguém sabe me dizer o porquê disso acontecer ?

## [Exemplo](http://jsbin.com/IZofafi/5/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Tecnicamente as `div` estão lado a lado dado tratarem-se de elementos "bloco", mas como não tem espaço para aparecer lado a lado, ficam visualmente umas por baixo das outras com margens colapsadas. Para esse aspecto final que pretendes obter, terás que usar `float:left;` para flutuar as mesmas para a esquerda, fazendo assim com que as margens sejam respeitadas na integra.

Comment: Justamente isso tem a ver com o display do elemento... http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/propriedade-css-display.php

Answer (score 16):

Quando há blocos empilhados, a margem inferior do bloco de cima é combinada com a margem superior do de baixo. O valor efetivo é o da maior margem, não a soma das duas. Isso se chama "colapso de margens", e está [descrito na especificação do CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
> might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
> that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
> margin is called a collapsed margin.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse, except:
>
> - Margins of the root element's box do not collapse.
> - If the top and
>   bottom margins of an element with clearance are adjoining, its margins
>   collapse with the adjoining margins of following siblings but that
>   resulting margin does not collapse with the bottom margin of the
>   parent block.

Tradução:

> Em CSS, margens adjacentes de dois ou mais *boxes* (que podem ou não ser irmãos na hierarquia do DOM) podem se combinar e formar uma única margem. Diz-se que margens que se combinam desta maneira se colapsam, e a margem combinada resultante é chamada de margem colapsada.
>
> Margens verticalmente adjacentes se colapsam; exceções:
>
> - Margens do box do elemento raiz nunca colapsam.
> - Se as margens superior e inferior de um elemento com *clear* forem adjacentes, suas margens colapsam com as margens adjacentes dos irmãos seguintes, mas a margem resultante não colapsa com a margem inferior do bloco pai.

Essa regra básica e outras descritas em seguida na especificação possuem as seguintes consequências (traduzidas da própria especificação):

> - Margens entre um box flutuado e qualquer outro box não colapsam (mesmo entre um *float* e seus descendentes que estiverem renderizados
>   "no fluxo"/*in-flow).
> - Margens de elementos que estabelecem novos contextos de bloco (como floats e elements com qualquer valor de 'overflow' exceto 'visible')
>   não colapsam com seus descendentes "no fluxo".
> - Margens de elementos com posição absoluta não colapsam (nem mesmo com seus descendentes "no fluxo").
> - Margens de boxes *inline-block* não colapsam (nem mesmo com seus descendentes "no fluxo").
> - A margem inferior de um bloco "no fluxo" sempre colapsa com a margem superior do próximo irmão que também esteja no fluxo e seja um
>   bloco, exceto se esse irmão possuir 'clear' definido com uma valor que
>   não seja 'none'.
> - A margem inferior de um bloco no fluxo com 'height' com valor 'auto' e 'min-height' com valor zero colapsa com a margem inferior de seu
>   último descendente imediato que seja um bloco e esteja no fluxo, se
>   esse bloco não possuir padding inferior nem borda inferior, e se a
>   margem desse elemento não colapsar com alguma outra margem superior
>   que possua 'clear' definido.
> - As margens de um box colapsam entre si se a propriedade 'min-height' tiver valor zero, e se ela não possuir bordas nem padding
>   superiores ou inferiores, tiver valor 0 ou 'auto' para 'height', e não
>   contiver um box de linha, contanto que todos seus descendentes diretos
>   no fluxo colapsem.

Sim, é complexo, diversos conceitos interações entre elementos precisam ser levadas em conta para se definir se vai haver ou não colapso de margens.

#### Solução

Na verdade não existe uma solução universal, depende do caso. O mais simples é usar `display: inline-block`, como você já apontou na pergunta, porém nem sempre isso dará o resultado visual desejado. A [solução do @utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1706/#1709) é mais genérica, mas tem cara de hack. Em certos casos, vale a pena simplesmente dobrar as margens dos elementos envolvidos. Outra possibilidade é usar `floats`, como [sugerido pelo @Zuul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1706/margin-top-e-margin-bottom-se-sobrepondo-por-que/1707#comment1684_1706).

Comment: A malta quer uma solução aqui na resposta :P

Comment: Excelente resposta @bfavaretto, muito obrigado! Realmente, acho que a melhor solução seria colocar o `display: inline-block` ou então utilizar somente `margin-top` ou `margin-bottom` com os valores dobrados como você sugeriu.

Comment: @WillianRibeiro No seu caso essa parece ser mesmo a solução mais simples. Mas fique de olho na resposta do utluiz, se ele conseguir algo com `:after` ou `:before`, seria uma boa.

Answer (score 3):

Esta resposta visa acrescentar algumas alternativas para quem precise alterar o comportamento padrão do CSS que culmina em *margin collapse*.

## Alternativa 1: elemento oculto (hack!)

Uma das soluções paliativas para evitar o efeito de ***margin collapse*** é incluir um elemento oculto entre os dois elementos com margem.

Exemplo:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="hidden">.</div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="hidden">.</div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.hidden {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 0px; 
    width: 0px;
}
```

#### Veja no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qumF9/1/).

Quanto às críticas sobre a criação de elementos adicionais, notem que mesmo usando `::after` ou `::before` via CSS também [há um *overhead*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249156/is-declaring-content-property-on-before-and-after-for-every-element-a-massiv), afinal o navegador precisa internamente criar aquele elemento. O mesmo vale para outras tags que geram processamento adicional.

Além disso, o usuário não estabeleceu uma quantidade de elementos. Não dá para supor que uma solução é ruim porque ela não serve para milhares de itens, quando essa quantidade é uma exceção e não a regra no desenvolvimento web em geral. Aliás, qualquer grande quantidade de itens pode travar certos sistemas e teríamos que jogar fora diversos frameworks web que encapsulam componentes complexos.

## Alternativa 2: dobrando a margem

Para quem não gostou do primeiro "hack", uma solução alternativa mais específica seria aumentar a margem inferior dos elementos. Para "corrigir" a margem sobrando no final é possível usar o `last-child`.

O CSS deste caso:

```css
.box {
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 48px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 14px 0px 7px 0;
}

.box:first-child {
    margin: 7px 0;
}
```

#### Exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hXb4/1/).

Bem, alguns ainda não gostaram dessa solução, apesar de não ter nada de absurdo. Mas, para quem quer achar pelo em ovo, mudei-a de `last-child` para `first-child` porque aparentemente em navegadores antigos (IE) [pode apresentar melhor desempenho](http://css-plus.com/2011/03/prevent-last-child-from-slowing-you-down/).

## Alternativa 3: `inline-block`

A última alternativa é usar a sugestão da [resposta do @bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1707/227).

O motivo pelo qual não postei uma alternativa usando o `inline-block` desde o início é que o navegador adiciona espaços adicionais entre os blocos e acabei não investigando a fundo o motivo.

Mas, depois de ressuscitarem o tópico alguns meses depois, resolvi fazer a investigação e a solução foi, afinal, até bem simples.

O espaçamento adicional é causado devido às propriedades de fonte, então bastou um `font-size` para resolver o problema.

Vejamos:

```css
.box {
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 48px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 7px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

#### Confira no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/eeqf7vto/).