# Não consigo definir margin-top/bottom/right para elemento block, por quê?

Tags: css, html

Tenho um elemento `<p>` dentro de uma `<div>`, dessa forma:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>texto</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Quando eu aplico `margin-left` funciona normalmente, o elemento `<p>` se distancia `10px` da esquerda, porém quando eu aplico `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` ou `margin-right` nada é alterado, o elemento `<p>` permanece na mesma posição. Eu não entendi o por quê, alguém sabe explicar este comportamento ?

[**Ver exemplo no JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/ovaGimA/2/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Temos um grande problema aí. Os dois elementos têm as mesmas dimensões e você está tentando ganhar mais espaço.

A `margin` do `p` está para fora da `div`, como é possível ver usando um web inspector:

[image: Margem em laranja]

Olhando a posição do `p`, ele está saindo de dentro da `div`:

[image: Sobreposição]

Para isso funcionar dessa maneira, precisaria de um `overflow: hidden` na `div` (para evitar que a `margin` colapse) e de `50px` de altura e largura (`30px` das dimensões + `20px` de margin, `10px` de cada um dos lados).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
  <div><p></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/IXInADEg/1/edit

Considere usar `padding` na `div` no lugar da `margin` no `p`. E, dependendo do conteúdo, usar `inline-block` em ambos os elementos pode ser mais útil.

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Dúvida esclarecida.

Answer (score 3):

A margem superior está sim sendo aplicada, o problema é que ela colapsa com a margem da div externa, e acaba sendo aplicada entre a div externa e o topo da página.

Você pode ver uma descrição detalhada de como isso funciona [nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1706/margin-top-e-margin-bottom-se-sobrepondo-por-que/1707#1707), mas a explicação bem resumida neste caso é a seguinte: quando você tem vários blocos aninhados, e somente o mais interno tem margem superior, essa margem acaba colapsando com a dos blocos ancestrais, e termina aplicada entre o mais externo e seu pai (aqui, o body).

Como isso só ocorre com blocos, a solução mais simples é transformar seu parágrafo em um `inline-block`:

```css
p {
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

<sup>[Demo no jsbin](http://jsbin.com/AdIZiGO/1/edit)</sup>

Comment: Outra forma simples de corrigir o problema é overflow:hidden.

Comment: Cleiton, fiz um teste com `overflow:hidden`, mas não resolveu.

Comment: Bfavaretto, segue um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/rLk36/.

Comment: @Cleiton Ah, é que o div externo da pergunta tem dimensões fixas. Aí o overflow:hidden corta o conteúdo.

Comment: Muito obrigado @bfavaretto! Realmente, sua resposta com a citação da documentação esclareceu muitas das minhas dúvidas (: