# Erro com CSS, barra aparece onde não deveria

Tags: html, css

Estou trabalhando em um projeto da faculdade em que preciso fazer um site para uma pizzaria. Estou fazendo um embrião do site, mas quando eu adiciono o menu de navegação, aparece uma barra em cima do `div` correspondente que não deveria existir:

[image: Aquela barra cinza em cima não deveria existir]

Porém, quando eu removo todo o menu, a barra some:

[image: Agora deu certo]

Por que isso acontece? Esse é o meu CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700,300);
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
#header {
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    height: 59px;
}
#content {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer {
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
.menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 17px 5px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

E o HTML onde estão o `div` do topo e o menu:

```
<div id="header">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pizzas Tradicionais</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pizzas Especiais</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pizzas Premium</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pizzas Integrais</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pizzas Doces</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bebidas</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Não estou conseguindo achar nenhum erro aparente nesse código. O que pode ser?

Comment: Não relacionado ao problema (que já foi resolvido pelo @abfurlan), mas quando você tiver `0` como medida, não ponha unidades: `margin: 0px;` => `margin: 0;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu `ul` esta com `margin`, veja:

```
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin:0;
}
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/5YD35/)

Comment: Não tenho como testar agora (estou indo pra aula), assim que puder testo e digo o que aconteceu.

Comment: resolveu meu problema, obrigado!

Comment: uma questão importante é que quando o valor de uma propriedade é zero não se usa unidade de medida, uma ação quando se cria o site é setar o `margin` e o `padding` em zero para todos os elementos

Comment: @leandro17br editei a resposta conforme sua obs...

Answer (score 4):

Este é um problema muito comum no CSS, onde a `margin` do elemento filho acaba empurrando o elemento pai junto para baixo.

Para resolver o problema, um simples `overflow:hidden` ou `auto` no elemento com a `margin` ja é suficiente:

```
.menu ul {
    overflow:hidden; /* ou auto */
    /* resto do código... */
}
```

#### Para ver um exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/e5Lsq/)

Comment: É isso mesmo, mas neste caso o [colapso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1707/74) não importa tanto (a menos que a intenção seja ter uma barra mais acima, com a cor do `#header`).