# Margen-top de DIV filha afasta ela e a DIV pai junta

Tags: html, css

Estou querendo que a `#div1` se afaste da `#fisrt` e que não leve a `#second` junto, porém não está funcionando com `margin-top: 5px;` na `#div1;`. Ou seja, entre a junção da `#first` com a `#second` quero que a `#div1` se afaste 5px sem levar a `#second`.

Segue o código:

```css
 * {
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0 0 0 0;
 }
    
 #first {
     background: blue;
     width: 100%;
     height: 34px;
 }
            
 #second {
     background-color: gray;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: red;
 }
    
 #div1 {
     background: green;
     width: 200px;
     height: 30px;
     margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="first">
</div>
<div id="second">
    <div id="div1"> Destaques </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seja devido ao box-model: [“margin-top” e “margin-bottom” se sobrepondo, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1707)

No caso basta adicionar um pixel no `#second` que deve resolver, também recomendo não adicionar `margin: 0 auto` no seletor global.

No caso adicione `padding-top: 1px;` e ao invés de `margin-top: 10px;`, troque por `margin-top: 9px;` para compensar o `1px`

**Extra:** Coloque o `margin: 0 auto;` apenas no `#div1`, já que ele é único que precisa ser alinhado no centro:

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

#first {
     background: blue;
     width: 100%;
     height: 34px;
}
       
#second {
     background-color: gray;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: red;
     padding-top: 1px;
}

#div1 {
     background: green;
     width: 200px;
     height: 30px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>

<div id="second">
    <div id="div1"> Destaques </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guilherme olá, porque não fazer só: `margin: 9px auto 0 auto;`? Escusavas de esplicitar `margin-top: ...` depois

Comment: @Miguel pode ser, de qualquer forma deixei como estava para o autor entender melhor o exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa definir uma posição para a div #second. No caso..
Só colocar float: left na div #second.

```css
 * {
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0 0 0 0;
 }

 #first {
     background: blue;
     width: 100%;
     height: 34px;
 }

 #second {
     background-color: gray;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: red;
     float: left;
 }

 #div1 {
     background: green;
     width: 200px;
     height: 30px;
     margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="first">
</div>
<div id="second">
    <div id="div1"> Destaques </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou tbm. E parece que é uma solução melhor que a de cima. Porém não tenho certeza. Obrigado.

Comment: @Amzero `float` também funciona, também pode-se usar o `overflow`, mas não citei tais técnicas pois elas podem lhe causar outros problemas e dificuldades se não forem bem aplicadas.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um pequeno exemplo, que não move as divs `first` e `second`, apenas a div filha com a propriedade `position: absolute`. Imagino que seja isso que buscava.

```css
 * {
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
 }

#first, #second {
     width: 100%;
     height: 34px;
     position: relative;
}
 #first {
     background: blue;
 }
            
 #second {
     background: red;
 }
    
 #div1 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 15px;
     left: calc(50% - 100px);
     background: green;
     width: 200px;
     height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second">
  <div id="div1"> Destaques </div>
</div>
```